# Generating an index page with Overleaf fails

Tags: compiling, indexing, overleaf

I want to add an index page to my project, so I tried to follow the [example](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/indices#Further_reading) on Overleaf's website. Their example works fine, but when I try it in my project no index page is generated, the entry doesn't appear in the TOC, and no errors are received when I compile.

Here is the code for my project -

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english,final,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
% Supplementry Packages
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,amsmath,ulem,listings}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true,              
 urlcolor=blue,citecolor =    red]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
citecolor=red,
filecolor=magenta,
urlcolor=blue,
}
% Supplementry Setup
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=3, title=Index, intoc]
\usepackage{abstract}

\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\absnamepos}{flushleft}
\setlength{\absleftindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\absrightindent}{0pt}


\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\selectlanguage{english}


\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\newpage

\begin{abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
Words words words
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\end{abstract}

\chapter{Introduction}


What are fractons\index{Fracton} 
Quantum computing - stability to thermal noise - topological order\index{Topological order} 

Gauss laws\index{Gauss Laws} Haah's code\index{Haah's code}    

\chapter{Stabilizer codes and linear algebra}
\section{Pauli operators and linear algebra}
\section{Stabilizer codes and Hamiltonians}
What are stabilizer codes, stabilizer group, logical operators, Yoshida's classification, binary vector representation, geometric algebra stuff from
Also a bit about error correction.

\chapter{Topological order}


\chapter{Logical operators}
\section{Equivalence of logical operators}


\chapter{Discussion}

\clearpage
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: We need to see some code. For the standard calsess the index is not automatically added to the TOC, there you might need the `tocbibind` package. Other classes can do this automatically. But without knowing anything about your document we have no clue.

Comment: @daleif Thank you, I added some code.

Comment: Note that hyperref should generally be the very last package loaded. On overleaf I would not use imakeidx just makeidx because the overleaf compiler uses latexmk which ouht to run makeindex automatically. If you remove imakeidx then remember to remove the options to the makeindex command. Additionally don't load Hebrew as the default language on an English example file. And use utf8 not utf8x

Comment: @daleif With `makeidx` you can't set the index to three columns. I see no problem in using `imakeidx` with `latexmk`.

Comment: @My file needs to include some text in Hebrew, and it fails to compile when I use `utf8`. Using `makeindex` doesn't change anything.

Comment: @proton I don't know with Hebrew, but I get the Index in the toc.

Comment: @egreg me neither, it was for debugging., especially when we know latexmk is involved, do we then get double makeindex?

Comment: @daleif If you have that doubt, load `imakeidx` with the `noautomatic` option.

Comment: @egreg I have no doubt at all, again it was to reduce this to the simplest case possible, plus I'm not at a pc. I will refrain commenting again

Comment: Without Hebrew the Index is generated as expected, with an entry in the TOC. How Do set English as the default language?